# Dispersion laws

Tags: frequency, dispersion

I am studying the dispersion law of the pressure $p(t)$ in order to obtain the wavenumber from the frequency.
In particular I am studying a discrete signal $p(t_{j})$. Once I have done the spectra $p(f_{i})$ with the dispersion law I can find $p(k_{q})$.

Doing this with matlab I have the frequency array $f_{i}$ and the velocity array $p(f_{i})$, and I simply apply the dispersion law $D$ to the array $f_{j}$ then I plot the dataset ($Df_{i}$,$p(Df_{i})$).

My question now is: if I consider $p^2(t)$ instead of $p(t)$, the dispersion law should be the same? In other words the above cited operator $D$ should be the same? Is there a relationship between the two dispersion laws (operators $D$)? Maybe what I call dispersion law considering $p^2(t)$, is more a change of variable. So knowing the dispersion law of $p(t)$ is it possible to estimate the "operator" to apply to $p^2(f_{j})$ to obtain the dispersion law?

I tried to find as more as possible information about the theory of dispersion law but I only found an old book of Brillouin and I am willing to find other relevant book about the dispersion laws

Comment: Why is pressure $p(t)$ only a function of time? Typically, pressure is a function of both space and time and its Fourier transform is a function $p(f,k)$, where $f$ is the frequency and $k$ is the wavenumber.

Answer (score 0):

If the operator $D$ is defined through the relationship $k_q=Df_q$, then as you said applying $D$ is nothing more than a change of variable. The relationship $k=Df$ is just a generic dispersion relation and it is something physical and true regardless of any function of $k$ you could pick.

Regarding the possibility of deducing $D$ from $p(t)$ alone, I don't see how it could be done.